# Request using SOAP XML

Tags: xml, soap, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to do a connection and retrieve some datas, like contact list, from Dynamics CRM.
I'm using Java language, method SOAP and XML to do this connection.
I already have a sample to get the name of the user admin. When I try to do others services, like RetrieveMultiple it says  "returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL". 
 
What can I do to resolve that? Am I replacing the things wrongly?

```
public static String CrmWhoAmI(CrmAuthenticationHeader authHeader, String url) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {

    StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
    xml.append("<s:Body>");
    xml.append("<Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\">");
    xml.append("<request i:type=\"c:WhoAmIRequest\" xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts\">");
    xml.append("<b:Parameters xmlns:d=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\"/>");
    xml.append("<b:RequestId i:nil=\"true\"/>");
    xml.append("<b:RequestName>WhoAmI</b:RequestName>");
    xml.append("</request>");
    xml.append("</Execute>");
    xml.append("</s:Body>");

    Document xDoc = CrmExecuteSoap.ExecuteSoapRequest(authHeader, xml.toString(), url);
    if (xDoc == null)
        return null;

    NodeList nodes = xDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        if ((nodes.item(i).getFirstChild().getTextContent()).equals("UserId")) {
            System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getLastChild().getTextContent());
            /*
             * RETURN USER GUID
             */
            return nodes.item(i).getLastChild().getTextContent();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public static String CrmGetUserName(CrmAuthenticationHeader authHeader,
        String id, String url) throws IOException, SAXException,
        ParserConfigurationException {
    StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
    xml.append("<s:Body>");
    xml.append("<Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">");
    xml.append("<request i:type=\"a:RetrieveRequest\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\">");
    xml.append("<a:Parameters xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">");
    xml.append("<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>");
    xml.append("<b:key>Target</b:key>");
    xml.append("<b:value i:type=\"a:EntityReference\">");
    xml.append("<a:Id>" + id + "</a:Id>");
    xml.append("<a:LogicalName>systemuser</a:LogicalName>");
    xml.append("<a:Name i:nil=\"true\" />");
    xml.append("</b:value>");
    xml.append("</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>");
    xml.append("<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>");
    xml.append("<b:key>ColumnSet</b:key>");
    xml.append("<b:value i:type=\"a:ColumnSet\">");
    xml.append("<a:AllColumns>false</a:AllColumns>");
    xml.append("<a:Columns xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">");
    xml.append("<c:string>firstname</c:string>");
    xml.append("<c:string>lastname</c:string>");
    xml.append("</a:Columns>");
    xml.append("</b:value>");
    xml.append("</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>");
    xml.append("</a:Parameters>");
    xml.append("<a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />");
    xml.append("<a:RequestName>Retrieve</a:RequestName>");
    xml.append("</request>");
    xml.append("</Execute>");
    xml.append("</s:Body>");

    Document xDoc = CrmExecuteSoap.ExecuteSoapRequest(authHeader,xml.toString(), url);

    /*
     * IF HAS ERROR 
     */
    if (xDoc == null)
        return null;

    /*
     * SELECT WHAT YOU WANT
     */
    String firstname = "";
    String lastname = "";

    NodeList nodes = xDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        if ((nodes.item(i).getFirstChild().getTextContent()).equals("firstname")) {
            firstname = nodes.item(i).getLastChild().getTextContent();
        }
        if ((nodes.item(i).getFirstChild().getTextContent()).equals("lastname")) {
            lastname = nodes.item(i).getLastChild().getTextContent();
        }
    }

    /*
     * RETURN WHAT YOU ASKED
     */
    return firstname + " " + lastname;
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? They may give you more detailed information.

Comment: That's the big problem, I do not have access to the server logs...

Comment: So the WhoAmIRequest Succeeds, but the Retrieve of the user fails?

Comment: Exactly... I change the RetrieveRequest to RetrieveMultipleRequest, change everything... but nothing successed. I understood the first XML Header gets the GUID of the adm and in the second one it send this GUID as a EntityReference to do the search... But I don't know how to do with others requests...